# Database connection failed for local MSSQL server with pymssql

Tags: python, database-connection, pymssql

I had been working with `pyodbc`for database connection in windows envirnment and it is working fine but now I want to switch to `pymssql` so that it is easier to be deployed to Linux machine as well. But I am getting this error:

> (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10060)\n')

My connection code for using both `pyodbc` and `pymssql` is:

```
    import pyodbc
    import pymssql

    def connectODSDB_1():
        conn_str = (
            r"Driver={SQL Server};"
            r"Server=(local);"
            r"Database=populatedSandbox;"
            r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
        )
        return pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

    def connectODSDB_2():
        server = '(local)'
        database = 'populatedSandbox'
        conn = pymssql.connect(server=server, database=database)
        return conn
```

What could be the problem? And solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well after browsing internet for a while, it seems `pymssql` needs TCP/IP be enabled for communication.

1. Open Sql Server Configuration Manager
2. Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
3. Click on Protocols for `instance_name`
4. Enable `TCP/IP`

Comment: If you want a static port e.g. `1433` then also verify: Right click `TCP/IP`, `Properties`, check `Listen All` is `Yes` and `IP Addresses` tab scroll to bottom and verify `IPAll` is [**blank**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-ip-addresses-tab?view=sql-server-ver16#static-vs-dynamic-ports) in `Dynamic Ports` and `1433` in `Port`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have faced the same issue while using RDS(AWS database instance). We should configured the inbound outbound rules.
>   Do following steps to configure.

```
Services->RDS->DB Instances -> Select DB-> Connectivity&Security
```

> Under Security Section

```
VPC security groups -> click on security group
```

> Change the inbound rules.

```
Check the source IP and change into anywhere or specific IP
```